# FindControl faux pas

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a FormView from which I am attempting to trigger an action based on input into one of the text boxes in that view.  What my intent to accomplish is throw control to the code behind 'protected void ARSControlNumTextBox_TextChanged' section where I want to stuff the contents of the TextBox in to a label (CurrentCtrl).

I have placed  a break point to observe what is going on as I'm not seeing the expected results. Here is the code in question:

```
 protected void ARSControlNumTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox thecontrol = (TextBox)ARS30InputFrm.Row.FindControl("ARSControlNum");
        if (thecontrol != null)
            CurrentCtrl.Text = thecontrol.Text;
    }
```

What takes place is that the value assignment is skipped. So it would seem that 'thecontrol' is null! which doesn't adde up.

Here is an abbreviated portion of the Formview so you can see where I'm getting my values from:

```
    <asp:FormView runat="server" ID="ARS30InputFrm" DataSourceID="ARFS" DefaultMode="Insert">
   <InsertItemTemplate>
        Control #:
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("ARSControlNum") %>' runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="ARSControlNumTextBox_TextChanged" ID="ARSControlNumTextBox" />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" ID="InsertButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" ID="InsertCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

And the label which is the ultimate target where the data it going from the TextBox:

```
Current Control Edit: <asp:Label ID="CurrentCtrl" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

I don't see what I am doing wrong here.  Someone else see it? If so I sure would appreciate some eyes on target because it is driving me off the bent end!
Regards,
Ken...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldnt it be

```
protected void ARSControlNumTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox thecontrol = (TextBox)ARS30InputFrm.Row.FindControl("ARSControlNumTextBox");
    if (thecontrol != null)
        CurrentCtrl.Text = thecontrol.Text;
}
```

Comment: yes you are correct and I'm blind as a bat... thank you!